# Улетает маркер в Google Maps при зумировании

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

При зумировании карты маркер меняет свой размер и вылетает за пределы области, выделенной под маркер. **Почему?**

До зумирования:

[image: До зумирования]

После зумирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инициализация карты :

```
function initMap() {
    var mapEl = document.getElementById('map');
    if (mapEl) {
        var place = {
            lat: 47.2345717, lng: 39.7319359
        };
        var position = {
          lat: 47.2266141, lng: 39.7383083
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapEl, {
            zoom: 16,
            center: place,
            //styles
        });
        var imageMarker = {
          url: '/images/icons/map_marker.svg',
          size: new google.maps.Size(39, 65),
        };
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: place,
            map: map,
            icon: imageMarker
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что в svg не указаны размеры. Посмотрите мой ответ на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669072/220220